# Changing the Contents of Table Cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-table

I'm new to JavaScript and my goal here is to change the color of the text in each cell of the table based on its content.  For some reason, it only works on the first column.

```js
function key() {
  var test = document.getElementById("schedule"),
    testChildS, testChild;
  var rows = test.rows.length;
  var columns = test.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

      testChildS = test.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      testChild = test.rows[r].cells[c];

      if (testChildS.includes("private")) {
        testChild.style.color = "red";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("qi gung")) {
        testChild.style.color = "tan";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("mini")) {
        testChild.style.color = "lightblue";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("kids")) {
        testChild.style.color = "blue";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("all")) {
        testChild.style.color = "pink";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("instructor")) {
        testChild.style.color = "purple";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("yang")) {
        testChild.style.color = "lightgreen";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("chen")) {
        testChild.style.color = "green";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("lion")) {
        testChild.style.color = "pink";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("adult")) {
        testChild.style.color = "blue";
      } else if (testChildS.includes("chinese")) {
        testChild.style.color = "lightpurple";
      } else {
        testChild.style.color = "black";
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onLoad = key();
```

Comment: Please make sure your question has a [mcve] and in this case, includes any relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that next time I have a question.

Comment: Why aren't you doing it for this question?

Answer (score 0):

try to get all cells like

```
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('table td');
```

and then iterate them

```
cells.forEach(cell => {...})
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go.